# Electron Intercept file:/// protocol to read inside zip files

Tags: javascript, electron

I would like to read inside zip archives with Electron as if they were folders, like so `/myfolder/myarchive.zip/picture.jpg`.  To do this I'm thinking about intercepting the file protocol

```
protocol.interceptFileProtocol('file', (request, callback) => {
    if (insideZipArchive) {
        //respond with zip file contents
    } else {
        //defaultBehavior
    }

  }, (error) => {
    if (error) console.error('Failed to register protocol')
  })
```

How do I invoke the default behavior?  Also doing an AJAX request inside the interceptor and serving files like this `callback({data: new Buffer(xhr.responseText)})`does not seem to work.

Comment: I ended up solving this problem by having a Node.js server extract and serve files from the ZIP archive.

Comment: Why do you need a server? Why can't you simply read the zip files from the renderer?

Comment: Because I was working with an existing code base, which used URLs to fetch files.  Reading the zip archives from the renderer would have required rewriting a lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this could be solved with a service worker, as shown here:

[How to intercept all http requests including form submits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813770/how-to-intercept-all-http-requests-including-form-submits)