# Vue dev proxy rule being ignored

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to proxy a link from unauthenticated landing page to localhost:8080 in development environment. For some reason, my proxy rule is being ignored.

```
static site: localhost:80
webapp: localhost:8080
```

From the static site I have:
`<v-btn href="https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com">Login</v-btn>`

`vue.config.js` within static project

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 80,
    proxy: {
      'https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible? Are `href` tags ignored by this setting? I've tried with `secure: false`, also have tried various proxy URLs, for example `^/mysubdomain.mydomain.com`. Regardless, I am sent to production subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

The dev server proxying only works when the network requests go *to* the dev server (localhost). For example, it could change `http://localhost/api/logo.png` to `https://example.com/logo.png`. It cannot intercept requests with third party destinations.

However, you could use a [service worker that rewrites network requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43815800/6277151). This has caveats, including having to reload the page for the new server worker to take effect (once to register the worker, and again to use it); and that you'd want to only load the service worker in development.

#### Using a Service Worker Proxy

1. Copy the following service worker to your static assets folder (e.g., `<projectRoot>/public/` in Vue CLI scaffold projects):

   ```js
   self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
     if (event.request.url.match(/https:\/\/mysubdomain.mydomain.com/)) {
       const redirect = event.request.url.replace(/https:\/\/mysubdomain.mydomain.com/, 'http://localhost:8080')
       console.warn('rewriting url', redirect)
       event.respondWith(fetch(redirect))
     } else {
       event.respondWith(fetch(event.request))
     }
   })
   ```
2. Edit your entry script (e.g., `<projectRoot>/src/main.js` in Vue CLI scaffold projects) to load the service worker:

   ```js
   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
     navigator.serviceWorker.register('/path/to/service-worker.js').then(registration => {
       console.log('Service worker registered with scope: ', registration.scope)
     }, err => {
       console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err)
     })
   }
   ```
3. *Hard reload* the browser to register the service worker. The requests are not yet proxied by the service worker until the next *normal reload*. You don't need to hard reload again unless the service worker is edited.