CSP report-to URL in an authenticated context
I am trying to use the report-to CSP directive to report policy violations. This works well if the specified endpoint is a public (non-authenticated) URL. However, I would like the reporting URL to require a JWT (all CSP protected pages are in an authenticated context). Is there a way to specify the Bearer header when the browser sends the report?

Not that I know of, or can find in any documentation. Not even sure if intercepting all requests made by the site using a ServiceWorker (https://stackoverflow.com/q/43813770/1427878) could help - because I don't know if this request is even within the "scope" of what can be manipulated using this technique.
